# Is my time conversion off and how can I fix it?

Tags: javascript

Currently converting unix time to readable time from an API. I'm not sure if it matters, but the time provided by the API is UTC. The current code that pulls the time looks like:

```
let start = new Date(api.startUTC * 1000);
let end = new Date(api.endUTC * 1000);
```

The rest of the code is mostly formatting the time:

```
let TimeDate = {
                hours: function hours(i) {
                  return "0" + i.getHours();
                },
                minutes: function minutes(i) {
                  return "0" + i.getMinutes();
                },
                seconds: function seconds(i) {
                  return "0" + i.getSeconds();
                },
                date: function date(i) {
                  return "0" + i.getDate();
                },
                month: function month(i) {
                  return "0" + i.getMonth();
                },
                year: function year(i) {
                  return i.getFullYear();
                }
              };

              // TIME AND DATE FORMATS

              // Date of Pass
              let passDate = `${TimeDate.date(start).substr(
                -2
              )}/${TimeDate.month(start).substr(-2)}/${TimeDate.year(
                start
              )}`;
              // Time of start of Pass
              let startPass = `${TimeDate.hours(start).substr(
                -2
              )}:${TimeDate.minutes(start).substr(
                -2
              )}:${TimeDate.seconds(start).substr(-2)}`;
              // Time of End of Pass
              let endPass = `${TimeDate.hours(end).substr(
                -2
              )}:${TimeDate.minutes(end).substr(-2)}:${TimeDate.seconds(
                end
              ).substr(-2)}`;
```

So if the API returns `1561020080`, the conversion from the above code shows it to be **10**:41:20 on the 20th of **May** 2019, which doesn't make sense as it's supposed to be forecasting events in the future. I put it into a website [like this one](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php) and the time returned was **08**:41:20 UTC on the 20th of **June** 2019 which, for the purposes of what I'm doing, makes more sense.

It seems my results are a month behind and 2 hours ahead. I have no idea why this is happening and I'm not sure if there's something wrong with the code I provided above or if I should add some more numbers to the result to match the answers I've got from that external website. In fact, I'm not even sure if the external website is correct, but it makes more sense than the results I've been getting.

I'm also aware that things like moment.js exists, but I'm just teaching myself how all of this works and I'd much rather do it myself so I can learn a bit more about it.

Thanks so much for the assistance!

Edit: Just wanted to add, that I think the time might be off because, [from what I understand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), it's converting to my local time from UTC. I can't explain why it shows a month behind though. My computer's date/time is accurate.

Comment: Not sure why the date is a month behind, but the time is being converted to local time. Your current timezone is UTC+2.

Comment: For some reason, months in javascript Date object are 0-based: 0 = January, 1 = February, etc. Look at them as indexes into a 0-based `Months` array.

Comment: @PeterB - of course! That totally makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getters you're using are timezone based and browser uses your current timezone. There are timezone indipendent getters like `getUTCHours()`. This should fix your problem with the hours.

The other problem is that months are 0 based. That means january is 0, february is 1, ... So you have to add 1 to your month to get the correct numerical representation.

Your code should then look like this:

```
let start = new Date(api.startUTC * 1000);
let end = new Date(api.endUTC * 1000);

let TimeDate = {
    hours: function hours(i) {
      return "0" + i.getUTCHours();
    },
    minutes: function minutes(i) {
      return "0" + i.getUTCMinutes();
    },
    seconds: function seconds(i) {
      return "0" + i.getUTCSeconds();
    },
    date: function date(i) {
      return "0" + i.getUTCDate();
    },
    month: function month(i) {
      return "0" + (i.getUTCMonth() +1);
    },
    year: function year(i) {
      return i.getUTCFullYear();
    }
};

// TIME AND DATE FORMATS

// Date of Pass
let passDate = `${TimeDate.date(start).substr(
-2
)}/${TimeDate.month(start).substr(-2)}/${TimeDate.year(
start
)}`;
// Time of start of Pass
let startPass = `${TimeDate.hours(start).substr(
-2
)}:${TimeDate.minutes(start).substr(
-2
)}:${TimeDate.seconds(start).substr(-2)}`;
// Time of End of Pass
let endPass = `${TimeDate.hours(end).substr(
-2
)}:${TimeDate.minutes(end).substr(-2)}:${TimeDate.seconds(
end
).substr(-2)}`;
```